# Count repeated fields value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I need to count how many times a value of a certain field appears, something [i]like[/i]:

```
Name    | Age | HowManyTimesTheNameRepeat  

Ghaleon | 21  | 3  
Ghaleon | 21  | 3  
Ghaleon | 21  | 3  
Bianca  | 20  | 2    
Bianca  | 20  | 2  
Carla   | 25  | 1
```

**EDIT**

I guess I confused the things. Here's my code:

```
SELECT t1.matricula AS Matricula, t1.descricao_debito AS Descricao, t1.quantidade AS Qtd,(SELECT COUNT(t2.name) FROM table1 AS t2 WHERE t1.name= t2.name) As MesmoNome
FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.dados_bancarios = t2.codigo
WHERE t1.dados_bancarios > 0 AND t1.configuracao =  2 AND t1.remessa = 116
GROUP BY t1.nome_titular
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

This is what I tried, so here is what I Really need:

I need to know how many times the same name repeats, but I can't use group by, because I need to receive every result row. Also, my *InnerJoin* does not happen by the field *name*.
Is it Possible?

Comment: I think you need to reevaluate your question, first you posted a single table now you have edited with a query that includes multiple table.  Please edit your question with the table details for both tablee, some sample data for each table and then the desired result.

Comment: Why did you post that humongous query? How is it related to the question or the example data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only had quick access to SQLite 3 but I assume this should work in MySQL just as well:

```
SELECT
    p1.Name,
    p1.Age,
    (SELECT count(p2.Name) FROM person AS p2 WHERE p1.Name == p2.Name) as QtdName
FROM person AS p1
```

Comment: There is no field *name* on the second table.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: What second table?

Comment: That I do the Inner join. p1 and p2, aren't they different tables?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: `p1` and `p2` are just aliases to the same `person` table; otherwise you can't do the subselect.

Comment: Got ya !! Worked :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers yield the correct result, however, for some reason, each of them uses a subquery.

This can become costly as your table grows!

Here's an alternative way to do this:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM test t 
 NATURAL JOIN 
 (SELECT name, count(name) FROM test GROUP BY name) AS t2;
```

This way the query for name counts does not get executed per every row in the table but only once.

Here's [an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb48d1/6) to show how this affects the performance. I created a simple schema and populated the table with 190 rows. I encourage you to take a look at the execution plans. Even for a small dataset like this, the difference is obvious. The version with subqueries takes about 10 times longer to execute.

Comment: Worked ! I have to go now, but as soon as possible I'll make a few tests and post here the result. Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, Count(name) As QtdName from table group by name
```

#### Edit

SELECT name, Count(name) As QtdName from table where name like "%somename%";

Comment: I did this, but It returns me a single row...  
Does it need to be the first one in the select order?  
Because I have a long select with inner join.  
It's the same thing I posted there... 
I have a lot of rows, I can't use groupby because I want to get all this rows as return.

Comment: Edited Comment. I need the return of all rows, that's why I can't use groupby.

Comment: Can you show your complete "long select"?

Comment: It worked some way. But besides of show the name of that name repeats, I need to get all the rows as it have not group by you know? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.name, 
(
  SELECT Count(s.name) As TempCount 
  FROM TableName as s 
  WHERE s.name = t.name 
) AS QtdName
FROM TableName as t
```

Replace all occurrences of TableName with the actual name of your table.

Comment: Thanks Linger. But I didnt get the *t* and *s* .Name. The Name appears only in a single table. The inner join that I do is with a different field.

Comment: That is fine.  You want all records.  You can't do a group by to get a value in one query and expect all the records.  So the group by has to be done in a sub query and added as a field in the main query.  I am referencing the same table in the sub query and main query.  I have to give them an alias in order for SQL to understand how I am linking everything together.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, Count(name) As QtdName 
FROM table 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: It worked some way. But besides of show the name of that name repeats, I need to get all the rows as it have not group by you know? Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to avoid code-only answers. At least a short piece of explanation on how the code addresses the problem is a nice-to-have.